# Why does Visual Studio Load Tests include Browser Mix if tests do not measure rendering time?

Tags: testing, load

As per title, Why does Visual Studio Load Tests include Browser Mix if the tests do not measure browser rendering time?
If the web tests are only meant to work at the protocol level (HTTP/HTTPS), i.e. make requests and receive responses from the server, why bother including browser information since this would be a client side interaction...?

Comment: Anyone able to help with this one?

Answer (score 1):

Adding different browsers to the mix sends different User-Agent http headers.  This allows you to test alternate execution paths and capture their results if your web application detects and returns different responses for different clients.